# VLC is unable to show desktop: open of `screen://' failed

Tags: vlc-media-player, desktop, streaming, screencasts

```
$vlc screen://
```

produces the following error:

```
core input error: open of `screen://' failed
```

I run

```
OS: Ubuntu artful x86_64
Kernel: 4.13.0-36-generic
DE: XFCE
WM: Xfwm4
```

I intend to livestream my PC desktop and audio to another device.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Same error when trying to record my screen with VLC 2.2.7 Umbrella on xfce 4.12.